# Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6235 Bluetooth: Ubuntu does not recognize the controller

Tags: pcie

Colleagues, tell me what should I do so that Ubuntu agrees to see the bluetooth controller on Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6235 and start working with it?

I chose this equipment not by chance - on my Mint laptop, Linux works fine with such a device and I have no problems.

On my desktop computer running Ubuntu, I used a USB bluetooth dongle made in South Korea, but it behaved very unstable, hung up, lost the keyboard, refused to connect another keyboard normally.

When I found that my HP Elitebook had no such problems and purchased the same mini-pcie controller as in it. I connected it through a mini-pcie - pcie adapter bought on Aliexpress.

Wi-Fi worked right away, but Ubuntu says about the Bluetooth that it does not see a single controller.

**Colleagues, tell me, please, how can I solve my problem and start working with the Bluetooth controller?**

Comment: Most probably the "adapter" does not live up to its expectations. Since Mint is a derivative of Ubuntu, it should work on Ubuntu. Does that "adapter" work on Mint?

Comment: @kanehekili Yes, it's the adapter. The cheap ones don't have the USB lanes required for Bluetooth so only WiFi works.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I ordered this adapter - https://aliexpress.ru/item/1005004043774448.html As far as I understand, it is absolutely minimalistic - a PCIe connector, a mini-PCIe socket and a power indicator. What else do you need to work with bluetooth?